# Hydrate warning with universal portal

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-portal

Some time ago I created for study purposes a universal portal (to work in SSR), very similar to this library: `@jesstelford/react-portal-universal`.

The whole thing about the universal portal is to collect the portal on a server without calling createPortal and then append them on the right selector.

```
let html = data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', <div id="root">${app}</div> );
    html = extractor.appendUniversalPortals(html);
    return res.send(html);
```

This is the project that I handled a custom universal portal: [Stack Blitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ssr-portal-talk-sample-aziads?file=src%2FApp.js)

The problems I can't find out are:

- Why am I facing issues (warning messages) when using `@jesstelford/react-portal-universal` with nextjs, but not on my project using my custom universal portal? ([Stackblitz Nextjs sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-smz9e1?file=pages%2Findex.js))If you guys run both stackblitz samples you will see that the nextjs one have a warning log but mine doesn't.
- Why do react warn me about something present on the initial markup? It is the same element, with the same attributes.
- Is the warning just a warning and doesn't affect the hydrate or does it affect it?
- Does this library `@jesstelford/react-portal-universal` wrong? Does the nextjs sample wrong? Does having a portal with the initial markup a wrong idea? How can I achieve such a feature without those messages?

I tried everything, looked for issues, reproduce universal portal with custom server and with nextjs. I just want to have the portal markup and hydrate it on client, is that possible?